# Writing file from PHP page android

Tags: java, php, android

In my project a compressed file is displayed on a php in bytes. 
I am trying to find a way to read the php page, decompress the file using **GZIP**, and write it out to the assets folder. 
The file that I am reading in has to be placed in the `data/data/package/database` file.

I have a class that reads a file from the assets folder and places the file into `data/data/package/database`.

Is it possible to write to the assets folder during runtime? If not is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if the PHP script is running on a server, your Android app will need to make an HTTP request to retrieve the content. of course then it has to store it somewhere. the SQLite database is a good option, but you could also store content in files on the SD card.

there are a couple ways to do the HTTP connection part of it, and they're written up on the [Android Dev Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).  Myself, I prefer the HttpURLConnection.